# Is Path attribute of cookies secure against JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, security, web, cookies

My JavaScript application may be run in a subfolder at a strange web server.

Is setting `Path` attribute of a cookie secure enough to prevent stealing secret data (with money!) from a user for whom I set the cookie by programmers managing other folders of the same server?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies :

> The `Path` attribute indicates a URL path that must exist in the requested URL in order to send the Cookie header.

Here it's said nothing about that the path must exist also in the requested URL also in order to allow JavaScript code of this path to retrieve the cookie.

Is it also secure when JavaScript History API is used to change the URL of the page without reloading?

Answer (score 2):

It is not secure:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#Security :

> It is important to note that the `path` attribute does *not* protect against unauthorized reading of the cookie from a different path. It can be easily bypassed using the DOM, for example by creating a hidden `<iframe>` element with the path of the cookie, then accessing this iframe's `contentDocument.cookie` property. The only way to protect the cookie is by using a different domain or subdomain, due to the same origin policy.